# Schedule Turn on/off android device programmatically on specific times

Tags: startup, shutdown

Hell all,
I am developing an android app on rooted device, and I need the power off this device on specific time say on 12:00 AM, and power on again after 8 hours, say on 8:00 AM.

I did a search on the internet, and I found some lines of code that do the shutdown process, the code is:

```
  try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                      .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
        proc.waitFor();

      } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }
```

The above code will shutdown the device only on rooted ones, what I need now is to create some timer or some line of code which will turn the device on on the desired time. any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simply not possible, once you turn it off you lose control over the device.

Comment: On some devices like Zidoo devices, it is possible, but you cannot generate this on all devices, you are right, thanks for your answer

Comment: @OmarTaha in Xiaomi devices is also possible. Did you find out how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Not really, on Xiaomi devices sometimes it works, and sometimes it does not.